# Как правильно сделать update в spring data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, jpa

Я понимаю, что согласно парадигме `spring data` у нас есть набор сущностей и всего один метод `save` для `update` и `insert`. Но что, если мне не надо добавлять новую запись в случае отсутствия такого первичного ключа ? Делать два запроса (смотреть, что такая запись уже есть и потом обновлять(но ведь это может быть дорого)) ? Или стоит сделать `@Query` для `update` (что кажется очень костыльным) ?

Answer (score 1):

Если хотите оптимально, то пишите запрос самостоятельно:

```
 @Modifying
 @Query("update SomeEntity t set t.value = :value where t.id = :id")
 int setValue(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("value") String value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте проверку перед save:

```
SomeEntity entity = someEntityRepository.findOne(id);
if(entity != null){
   entity.setSomeValue(value);
   someEntityRepository.save(entity);
}
```

Comment: Да, это один вариантов, которые я указал: Делать два запроса (смотреть, что такая запись уже есть и потом обновлять(но ведь это может быть дорого))

Comment: Если для вас накладно, тогда используйте: 
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0):

Используя пример Atrem, важно добавить, что нужно аннотировать @Transactional тот метод сервиса, который выполняет update/delete.

```
@Modifying
@Query("update SomeEntity t set t.value = :value where t.id = :id")
int setValue(@Param("id") Long id, @Param("value") String value);
```