# Spring Data JPA обновить или проигнорировать записи при нарушении ограничения первичного ключа

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

У меня есть огромная сущность `Organization`, которая связана с сущностью `OrganizationEmail` вязью один-ко-многим. Эта сущность создается из данных, которые приходят из блокчейна. Возникает проблема при сохранении дублирующихся емейлов.

Дело в том, что для того, чтобы не сохранять дубликаты, мы сделали составной первичный ключ в таблице емейлов (она называется `organization_email`).

Сущность `Organization` вместе с привязанным к ней списком емейлов сохраняется в репозитории, который `extends JpaRepository`). Проблема в том, что при сохранении списка емейлов, в котором есть уже существующие в базе емейлы, возникает нарушение ограничения первичного ключа. Как можно решить эту проблему?

Приведу пример самого важного кода:

Это в сущности `Organization`:

```
@Column(name = "emails")
    @JsonProperty("emails")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "organization",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OrganizationEmail> emails;
```

А это в сущности `OrganizationEmail`:

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "organization_msp", referencedColumnName = "msp", nullable = false)
    private Organization organization;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private EmailType type;
    private String email;
```

Как при сохранении этой шляпы в репозитории обновить существующие емейлы, а не инсертить их? Почему-то в `JpaRepository` отсутствует метод update.

Нужно обновлять емейлы только в том случае, если они уже есть в базе, или вообще их проигнорить. Наверное, мне нужен аналог запроса `insert or update` в sqlite или поведение ignore on duplicate key. Мы используем постгрес.

Как это сделать?

Comment: вы случайно не про merge/persist говорите?

Comment: @Dred, похоже на то, но в JpaRepository нет таких методов.

Comment: Видимо, вам необходимо [так](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/JpaRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-) что вызовет [это](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html#saveAll-java.lang.Iterable-) Еще можно попробовать через собственные запросы. [тут](https://devcolibri.com/spring-data-jpa-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BC-dao-%D0%B8-services-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-2/) в самом конце описано. Ну и [вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/739738/216510)

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю, что вы пытаетесь сохранить в Организацию чужие Имейлы (т.е. которые уже есть в базе) и хотите без предупреждения пользователя молча "проигнорировать" такие записи??

Comment: @Cepr0, Нет, неправильно. Ошибка возникает из-за того, что существующие емейлы сначала отображаются на фронте, там к ним могут добавиться другие емейлы и все это сохраняется в бд

Comment: @typemoon 1) С фронта прилетает DTO на обновление всей Организации целиком, включая список связанных Имейлов, или отдельный DTO на обновление только списка Имейлов? 2) Редактирование списка Имейлов подразумевает их только добавление и обновление, или удаление тоже есть? Если есть - что должно происходить в этом случае, удаление из БД или что-то другое? 3) Как должна отреагировать система, если в обновленном списке Имейлов появится Имейл, который уже есть в БД? Нужно завалить всю транзакцию или обработать весь список Имейлов, кроме проблемного, и сообщить о нем на Фронт в респонсе?

Comment: @Cepr0, прилетает ДТО на обновление всей организации, включая список емейлов. Удаление емейлов тоже есть. При удалении происходит физическое удаление емейла из таблицы. Если приходит емейл, который уже есть в базе, этот емейл надо проигнорировать или обновить существующий (то есть заменить существующий емейл точно таким же емейлом)